# How to move a row to the top of the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

```
var data = $('tbody');

console.log(data.filter(':first'), data.filter('tr.ay-sort-top'));

data.filter(':first').before(data.filter('tr.ay-sort-top'));
```

Console output from two runs:

```
[<tr class=​"ay-sort-top">​…​</tr>​] [<tr class=​"ay-sort-top">​…​</tr>​]
[<tr>​…​</tr>​] [<tr class=​"ay-sort-top">​…​</tr>​]
```

Answer (score 4):

For example: `$('tr:eq(2)').prependTo('table');​`

See DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/LxKSq/2/

Comment: You can omit `.remove()` (because `.prependTo()` will _move_ the elements - assuming there is only one target element).

Comment: You're welcome. (Note that of course when there is more than one target element it makes clones.)

Answer (score 0):

If your question is actually "How do I move any rows with the "tr.ay-sort-top" class to the top of the table, leaving other rows in place?" then you can do something like this:

```
var $tbody = $("#yourTable tbody");
$tbody.prepend( $tbody.find("tr.ay-sort-top") );
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b89zY/1/